# Fallo select dependientes en Internet Explorer (PHP, Javascript)

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo un aplicativo que utiliza select dependientes sin problemas en Firefox y Chrome pero no funcionan correctamente en Internet Explorer. La idea general es que según el municipio seleccionado muestre unas oficinas u otras. Pongo el código para ver si podéis ayudarme, gracias de antemano.

Este es el archivo modulousuarios.php donde se seleccionará el municipio escogido:

```
<label for="municipio">Municipio</label>
<select class="form-control"  name="municipio" id="municipio" title="Municipio de la oficina" onchange="carga_oficinas(this.value,'')"/>
```

...

carga_oficinas se encuentra en  js/funciones.js. Mediante onchange se llamará a la función javascript carga_oficinas.js ubicada en js/funciones.js

```
function carga_oficinas(municipio,elegido){
var strURL="oficinas.php?municipio=" + municipio + "&elegido="+elegido+"&nocache=" + Math.random();
var req = nuevoAjax();
if (req)
{
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (req.readyState == 4) 
        {
            if (req.status == 200) 
            {                       
                document.getElementById('ofidiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;                       
            } 
            else
            {
                alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
            }
        }               
    }           
    req.open("GET", strURL, true);
    req.send(null);
}
```

}

Y, por último, oficinas.php.

```
   <?php
    $sel = 0;
    $elegido = 0;

    if (isset($_GET['municipio']))
    {
        $sel = $_GET['municipio'];
    }

    if (isset($_GET['elegido']) && $_GET['elegido'] != '')
    {
        $elegido = $_GET['elegido'];
    }       
?>
        <label for="oficina">Oficina</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="oficina" name="oficina" onchange="carga_dptos(this.value,'')">
            <option value="">Seleccione oficina ...</option>
<?php
            do
            {
?>
                <option value="<?= $ofi['id_oficina']; ?>" <?php if ($elegido == $ofi['id_oficina']) {echo "selected";}?>><?= $ofi['oficina']; ?></option>;
<?php
            } while($ofi = mysql_fetch_assoc($ofis));
?>
        </select>
<?php
```

He descartado algunas partes del código para evitar tanto contenido pero creo que lo más importante está reflejado

Comment: ¿Y, cuál es el comportamiento en IE, en qué falla, revisaste la consola, hay algún error?

Comment: Buenas tardes A. Cedano, en IE no hace nada, simplemente no responde ante la selección del municipio, no llega al método carga_oficinas y en la consola no aparece ningún error tampoco...

Comment: Poner funciones *in line*  en JS se considera una mala práctica. Empecemos por lo básico, cambia esto: `<select class="form-control"  name="municipio" id="municipio" title="Municipio de la oficina" onchange="carga_oficinas(this.value,'')"/>` por simplemente esto: `<select class="form-control"  name="municipio" id="municipio" title="Municipio de la oficina" />` o sea, quita la función `onchange` de ahí, identifica el elemento por su `id` en JS y asígnale allí un evento `onchange` prueba con un alert si funciona. Eso es lo primero, luego podremos seguir depurando.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por su respuesta. Ya he hecho las modificaciones oportunas conforme a lo que me has comentado, no hay problema en cuanto a que llega al método carga_oficinas.js y este no da error pero sigue sin cargarme el listado de oficinas, parece que no llega al archivo oficinas.php (aunque la url generada parece correcta). En Chrome sigue funcionándome con estos cambios añadidos

Comment: Ok. Seguimos depurando, ¿verificaste la respuesta de Ajax? ¿Trae un código 200, o trae otro código? ¿Qué código? ¿Trae mensajes de error? ¿Qué mensaje? Tienes que capturar eso y mostrarlo y decirnos qué ocurre. Son pasos básicos de depuración ante cualquier problema, para ver si es un problema en el servidor o en el cliente.

Comment: Buenos días, he estado unos días fueras, de ahí mi tardanza en responder. He mirado en la consola y al seleccionar el municipio da error en la línea
 document.getElementById('ofidiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;  
de carga_oficinas.js